# What are some useful use cases of reduce method in Dataset

Tags: apache-spark

What could be some useful use cases of the `reduce` method in `Dataset`.

I have the following table

```
DEST_COUNTRY_NAME   ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME count
United States       Romania             15
United States       Croatia             1
United States       Ireland             344
Egypt               United States       15
```

The table is represented as a Dataset.

```
scala> dataDS
res187: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[FlightData] = [DEST_COUNTRY_NAME: string, ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME: string ... 1 more field]
```

I can't think of any useful scenario to use the `reduce`  method in `dataDS`. I suppose `reduce` method would pick two rows (represented as `FlightData`) and would do some operation in it which should be mathematically associative and cumulative and the result should be `FightData`

`(func: (FlightData, FlightData) => FlightData)FlightData`

Maybe the table above doesn't fit the purpose of `reduce`. Which type of data then would fit `reduce`?

Answer (score 1):

Dataset is statically typed from a case class `FlightData` in this question. So, you can use scala imperative functional way such as reduce, group by key. The main benefit is Spark will automatically serialize your case class. For example, you can use Scala `map`, `reduce`, and `foldleft` functions to apply aggregation or transformation over your Dataset.

```
val totalSum = dataDS.map(_.count).reduce(_+_)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose I can use `reduce` when I want to either add or multiply the entire column. Eg., say I want to sum all the values of the count column.

```
scala> (dataDS.select(col("count").as[Int])).reduce((acc,n)=>acc+n);
```